# Get innerHTML of content when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the text of the **`p`** tag to change to the text from the **`li`** that tag I click. However, It always changes to the first one.

**Javascript**

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('p').html($('li').html());
})
```

**HTML**

```
<p>text</p>
<ul id='ul'>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('li').html()` will grab the HTML of the *first matching `li` element*. Use `this` instead, to refer to the `li` that was clicked on. But, since you aren't inserting HTML markup, but just plain text, it would be more appropriate to use the `.text` methods:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $('p').text($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>text</p>
<ul id='ul'>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Or, if you wanted, no need to include a big library like jQuery for something as simple as this:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
document.querySelector('#ul').onclick = ({ target }) => {
  p.textContent = target.textContent;
};
```

```html
<p>text</p>
<ul id='ul'>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` to refer the currently clicked `li`. Also since you are trying to get/set the text content, I will suggest you to use `text()` instead of `html()`:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
    $('p').text($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>text</p>
<ul id='ul'>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Congrats on your first question.

You want `this` to target the element you've clicked instead using jQuery to find a `li` element like so:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('p').html($(this).html());
})
```

I've created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/74708/

Comment: Instead of jsfiddle.net, use the Code Snippet feature in the WYSIWYG so people don't have to navigate off the site to see your example.

Comment: I prefer jsfiddle.net. It has a more robust compatibility with different libraries, it's easier to navigate and edit on the fly, and plenty of people are comfortable with its UI.